# Touchpad freezing, detection issues, 17.10 on Acer Swift 1

Tags: touchpad, 17.04, acer, synaptics

Recently picked up an Acer Swift SF113 and installed Xubuntu 17.04.  Touchpad will usually work perfectly for a while, but then freezes or stops responding.  Haven't figured out a pattern as to what triggers it, but it usually gives up within a couple minutes of opening a browser.  Can usually get it back by disabling and enabling it in xinput, but after a few times that doesn't work, or rather the buttons are responsive, but no touch.  A USB mouse consistently works.  At one point the touchpad wasn't recognized at all even through several reboots, but back to previous behaviour after booting into windows then back to Xubuntu.

Tried a daily 17.10 build, but touchpad wasn't recognized at all.  Tried Manjaro 17.02 and perhaps had less freezing issues, but still got a freeze or two before giving up on that.

Ideas? Everything else work so perfectly..

```
$ uname -a
4.10.0-32-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 12:10:06 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2     [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer           id=4     [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                    id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad       id=10    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3     [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard          id=5     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                            id=6     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                         id=7     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                         id=8     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                            id=9     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard         id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                     id=12    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i synaptics
[     8.775] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[     8.775] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[     8.775] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     8.775] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad'
[     8.817] (II) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: found clickpad property
[     8.817] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 1223 (res 12)
[     8.817] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 745 (res 12)
[     8.817] (II) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: device does not report pressure, will use touch data.
[     8.817] (II) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: device does not report finger width.
[     8.817] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[     8.817] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x7dac
[     8.817] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: invalid pressure range.  defaulting to 0 - 255
[     8.817] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: invalid finger width range.  defaulting to 0 - 15
[     8.817] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: touchpad found
[     8.856] (**) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[     8.856] (**) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[     8.856] (**) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.140
[     8.858] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: touchpad found
[   139.276] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: touchpad found
[   175.292] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: touchpad found
[   442.940] (--) synaptics: SYNA7DAB:00 06CB:7DAC Touchpad: touchpad found
```

Behaviour is the same in kernel 4.12 and 4.13 RC6

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and took the following steps. http://www.cogitolingua.net/blog/2017/11/12/acer-swift-1/

1. ```
   apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
   ```

   for some reason this does not install with xserver-xorg-input-all. It’s presence opens up a bunch of configuration options regarding click behavior, scrolling, palm detection, etc.
2. Create a script that will cycle the touchpad when it freezes and create global keyboard shortcut to run it. If the touchpad freezes, at least you have a button to get it back.

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   declare -i ID
   ID=`xinput list | grep -Eio '(touchpad|glidepoint)\s*id\=[0-9]{1,2}' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}'`

   xinput disable $ID
   sleep 0.1
   xinput enable $ID
   ```

   I spent a day using this setup and must have hit the cycle button at least 50 times. Though it was quick, it got really annoying.
3. If the touchpad doesn’t come back after using the above script, then you can cycle the responsible kernel module.

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r hid_multitouch
   sudo modprobe hid_multitouch
   ```

Once the touchpad didn’t respond after resuming from sleep. So I dug deeper to see if I could virtually unplug and replug it.

4. Change the bios settings. During bootup press F2 to access the bios, then switch Main > Touchpad from Advanced to Basic.

I have not had to cycle the touchpad (step 2) since changing the bios flag (step 4).

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Arch on an Acer Swift 1 and have run into the same problem. Quickly switching to a separate terminal then back to X also reloads the touchpad and gets it working again.. just a quick ctrl +alt+f6 then f7 and you are back

still an annoying problem but it is the perfect lightweight laptop so its worth putting up with until touchpad drivers improve

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a hardware problem as described here:
http://www.iq-tm.de/TP%20freeze.htm

Had the same problem on my Acer Swift 1 after 3 days and therefore sent it back...